# Convert GRIB to JSON object

Tags: json, grib

Previously I have worked on a project that reads and displays wind direction forecast using GRIB data retrieved from the following NOAA website:

http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_1p00.pl

The GRIB data downloaded is then converted to JSON object using utility tool 'grib2json'.

However, I was asked to take in GRIB data from the following Japan website instead:

http://www.wis-jma.go.jp/d/o/RJTD/GRIB/Global_Spectral_Model/Latitude_Longitude/1.25_1.25/60.0_-20.0_60.0_200.0/925hPa/

However, I realized that the GRIB format for both sources is different. And the utility 'grib2json' does not work on GRIB data from Japan.

I need help on how to convert the Japan GRIB data to JSON so that I can still reuse my source codes to display the wind direction forecast.

Comment: From what I can tell, the Japanese website is using the Grib v1 format whereas NOAA is using Grib v2.